# Time and Attendance Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Somebody please help me,to sort out my time and attendance SQL query 
I have an SQL table with fields ID,Date,Time,StaffNo,TranType ( this will be two values 1,2 1 = in 2=out) I want output like this id Date StaffNo In-time Out-Time

Comment: what you have tried?????

Comment: your question is not understandable.

Comment: Thanks Ammar and Pouya for your response

Answer (score 0):

**Is this you are looking for.?**

*Table Declaration*

```
create table #tab  (id int primary key ,[date] date,[time] varchar(10),staffno int,trantype int)
insert into #tab values (1,'2013-01-01','12:31:09',101,1),(2,'2013-01-01','12:51:09',101,2),(3,'2013-01-01','09:31:09',102,1)
select * from #tab
```

Sample Code Required as per my understanding.

```
select 
x.date,x.StaffNo,max(x.timeIn) timeIn,max(x.timeOut) timeOut
from
(   
    select 
    StaffNo,[date],
    timeIn = (case when trantype = 1 then ([time]) else '' end),
    timeOut = (case when trantype = 2 then ([time]) else '' end)

    from
    #tab
) x
group by 
x.date,x.StaffNo
```

Comment: Dear Kishore,Thanks for the answer,Yes this is I was looking for,But the time is not displaying properly,Do I need to add some formatting?

Comment: CAn u pls share your query with the result set.

Comment: SELECT     date, pin, MAX(timeIn) AS timeIn, MAX(timeOut) AS timeOut
FROM         (SELECT     pin, date, (CASE WHEN transtype = 7 THEN ([etime]) ELSE '' END) AS timeIn, (CASE WHEN transtype = 8 THEN ([etime]) ELSE '' END) AS timeOut
                        FROM         dbo.Transactions1) AS x
GROUP BY date, pin

Comment: Dear Kishore Kindly find above SQL I applied PIN is staff Number

Comment: and Transtype 7 =IN and Transtype=8 is OUT,i am looking for number of hours worked in each day of an employee

Comment: Sorry I am not able to post the result set

Comment: Try this select 
x.date,x.StaffNo,max(x.timeIn) timeIn,max(x.timeOut) timeOut
,HrsWorked =  datediff(hour,
 (convert(varchar(12),x.date) + ' '+ convert(varchar(20),max(x.timeIn))),
 (convert(varchar(12),x.date) + ' '+ convert(varchar(20),max(x.timeOut))))
 
from
(   
    select 
    StaffNo,[date],
    timeIn = convert(varchar(20),(case when trantype = 1 then ([time]) else '' end)),
    timeOut = convert(varchar(20),(case when trantype = 2 then ([time]) else '' end))

    from
    #tab
) x
group by 
x.date,x.StaffNo

Comment: Thanks Kishore, and sorry for the late reply ,Thanks for the new query but I got this error message "Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value."

Comment: Kishore,my time data type is datetime ,I think in your table creation you are using varchar(10)